NameError when accessing variable returned from function (out of order?)
Per the code below, I'm getting this error:

NameError: name 'leap_status' is not defined

The def days_in_month() is looking for the status of leap_status which should be defined already but, for some reason, it seems to be calling it before it's defined by the is_leap() function?
I feel like I missed something about how the return value is stored or something..
def is_leap(year):
  if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0:
      if year % 400 == 0:
        leap_status = True
      else:
        leap_status = False
    else:
      leap_status = True
  else:
    leap_status = False
  return leap_status

def days_in_month(year, month):
    if leap_status == True:
        month_days = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    else:
      month_days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] 
    num_days_in_month = month_days[month -1]
    return num_days_in_month


#Year Input from user
year = int(input()) # Enter a year
#Function to calculate if Leap Year
is_leap(year)
#Month Input from User
month = int(input())
#Function to determine how many days in month
#depending on if Leap Year is True
days_in_month(year, month)
days = days_in_month(year, month)


Your code assumes leap_status is a global variable, but never defines it as such inside of is_leap, so it assumes leap_status is local to that function.

You shouldn't be relying on global variables anyway, call is_leap at the place you need it.

The reason of the error is because you use the variable out of scope. the leap_status variable is locally in is_leap function and out of the function python doesn't know this variable.
You can solve it in two ways:
First, and recommended, is to call the function and not the variable:
def days_in_month(year, month):
    if is_leap(year):
        # rest of code

In here, you call the first function that is above the function you are in, so the is_leap function is called and known by python. be aware the if the is_leap function was down the days_in_month function you can't do it.
The second and less recommended way is to use global variable, so python know to use the variable in other places, out of the declared function:
def is_leap(year):
    global leap_status
        # rest of code

This way when you can use or change the variable where ever you want in your program.

Actually there's no problem if is_leap is defined after, as long as both are defined before you make the call.

The reason for the error is leap_status is declared in the function is_leap() and it if leap_status == True: is found in the function days_in_month. We call it leap_status is a local variable of is_leap() meaning: you can't call this variable from another function. So, instead of if leap_status == True: in the function days_in_month(), you can change the statement as if is_leap(year): (True doesn't need to be mentioned in the conditional statements.)
To avoid these kinds of confusions, provide your code either as completely pseudo code or completely with proper code with function. Pseudocode is nothing but not defining the function and getting result. Here, we use input() and print statements.
In the code with function, we provide the input as the parameters of the function.
Your code seems to be mix-up of Pseudocode(Without defining function) and code with function.
it is generally said not to use global variables.
This is pseudocode:
year = input()
month = int(input())
if len(year) != 4:
    print("Enter the year in 'YYYY' format")
else:
    year = int(year)
l = [x for x in range(12)]
non_leap_months = [31 if i%2==0 else 28 if i==1 else 30 for i,x in enumerate(l)]
leap_months = non_leap_months.copy()
leap_months[1] = 29 
   
if year % 400 != 0:
    if year % 100 != 0 and year % 4 == 0:
        leap_status = True
    else:
        leap_status = False
   
else: leap_status = True
    
if leap_status:
    month_days = leap_months
else:
    month_days = non_leap_months

num_days_in_month = month_days[month -1]

print(leap_status)
print(num_days_in_month)

Defining as Function and getting result:
def leap_year_finding(year):
    
    year_str = str(year)
    
    # if the year is not with 4 digits, return error
    if len(year_str) != 4:
        return "Enter the year in 'YYYY' formate"

    else:
        
        # list of 0 - 11, leap_months and non_leap_months
        l = [x for x in range(12)]
        non_leap_months = [31 if i%2==0 else 28 if i==1 else 30 for i,x in enumerate(l)]
        leap_months = non_leap_months.copy()
        leap_months[1] = 29
        
        
        #leap year_conditional_statements
        if year % 400 == 0: leap_status = True
        else:
            if year % 100 != 0 and year % 4 == 0:
                leap_status = True
                
            else: leap_status = False
        
            
        if leap_status: month_days = leap_months
            
        else: month_days = non_leap_months
        
        # return a list of leap_status and leap_months   
        return [leap_status, month_days]

def is_leap(year):
    return leap_year_finding(year)[0]

def num_days_in_month(year,month):
    r = leap_year_finding(year)[1]       
    return r[month-1]
    
    

r = is_leap(1900)
print(r) # Output: False
r = num_days_in_month(1900,2)
print(r) # Output: 28

r = is_leap(2000)
print(r) # Output: True
r = num_days_in_month(2000, 2)
print(r) # Output: 29

r = is_leap(2004)
print(r) # Output: True
r = num_days_in_month(2004, 2)
print(r) # Output: 29

r = is_leap(2004)
print(r) # Output: True
r = num_days_in_month(2004, 5)
print(r) # Output: 31

r = is_leap(2008)
print(r) # Output: True
r = num_days_in_month(2008, 5)
print(r) # Output: 31
r = num_days_in_month(2008, 6)
print(r) # Output: 30

r = is_leap(2009)
print(r) # Output: False
r = num_days_in_month(2009, 2)
print(r) # Output: 28
r = num_days_in_month(2009, 3)
print(r) # Output: 31

